# Best way to display a custom Google maps multiple image marker icon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have two images, one is like an icon and the other is the icon background, what is the best way to combine these two images and make a google marker v3 icon? They are not svg or paths, they are just two png images.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS Maps v3: custom marker with user profile picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965161/js-maps-v3-custom-marker-with-user-profile-picture)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way: Use an image editor to make a single image and use that as the [icon for your custom marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons).

If you can't or don't want to do that you can make a [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays) ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView)) that behaves like a marker and use it to overlay the two images in the correct order on the map.

Comment: I was hoping to get a more practical example since I came to Custom Overlay by myself but I'm having problem trying to combine two PNG images (it has to be set dynamically a reason why I can't just use an image editor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an excellent little library, [RichMarker](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/). Its documentation is [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/docs/reference.html).

To make usage easier, you can even create your own custom marker class, something like this:

```
Ns.Marker = function(properties) {

    RichMarker.call(this, properties);

    this.setContent('<div class="three-images-marker">' +
            properties.NsImage ? '<div class="marker-image-1"><img src="'+properties.NsImage1+'"/></div>' : '' + 
            properties.NsFrameImage ? '<div class="marker-image-2"><img src="'+properties.NsImage2+'"/></div>' : '' +
        '</div>');
};

Ns.Marker.prototype = Object.create(RichMarker.prototype);


// and use it like this:
var gorgeousMarker = new Ns.Marker({
      position: yourMarkerLatlng,
      map: yourMap,
      NsImage: 'example.com/image.png',
      NsFrameImage: 'example.com/frame.png',
});
```

'Ns' is whatever namespace you use, if you do.

From here on it's CSS work, you can position the images as you like.